# How to get detailed logs for Planning and Create Build Description stage in building a SPM package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, swift-package-manager

This question is similar to this Swift Form post:

https://forums.swift.org/t/xcode-build-is-hanging-at-the-planning-build-phase-with-local-spm-packages/47881

My build is not hanging like the one in this question. However I am seeing some very odd things. My package is also quite complex with around 100 dependencies. When building this massive target, I see the follow build stages:

1. Planning
2. Create build description
3. Compilation

The first 2 steps take a long time. And even on an incremental build they take just as long. After that the actual compilation happens quite quickly. Is there any way to read logs for what SPM/Xcode does during the first 2 steps? Trying to see if there is scope for optimization. But can't make much progress without some logs.